# How to decompose a string into two parts (which are column name and its value)

Tags: r, strip

I'm dealing with the output of a caret package where it lists the important variable. Now if there a factor variable the output matrix will have it as columnnameValue.

I'd like to separate columnname part of it so I can run some analysis on it.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('life_stageAdult','books', 'bags', 'educationMasters'), col2 = c(100, 90, 80, 70))
original_column_names <- c('life_stage','books', 'bags', 'education', 'gender')
```

I want my output to be:

```
factot_cols = c('life_stage','education')
```

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you want, but can you just do factot_cols <- colN[!colN %in% df$col1]?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset <- data.frame(life_stage=rep(c("Adult","Child"),n=5),
                  books = c(1:10),
                  bags = rep(c(1,0),n=5),
                  education = rep(c("Bachelors","Masters"),n=5))
# List of variables you entered in the model
model_vars <- c("life_stage","books","bags","education")

levels_dataset <- dataset %>%
 select(model_vars) %>% 
 summarise_each(funs(as.numeric(length(levels(.))))) %>% 
 unlist()

levels_dataset <- ifelse(levels_dataset==0,1,levels_dataset-1)

names_dataset <- rep(names(dataset),levels_dataset)

#Your model output 'df' with columns

df <- data.frame(col1 = c('life_stageAdult','books', 'bags', 'educationMasters'), 
             col2 = c(100, 90, 80, 70))

df <- data.frame(df,names_dataset) %>% 
  mutate(level = str_replace(col1,
                         pattern = as.character(names_dataset),""))
```